# Formatting date like medium date SQLite

Tags: date, sqlite, date-formatting

How to format date in SQLite to get like `10-Jan-2014`. What formatting string I need.
I have seen this [SQLite date formatting](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and other questions but did not find my answer.
The given link formats the date to only numeric like `2014-01-10` etc.

Any one know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Month names are not supported in SQLite.

You can use a lookup table to make and get your desired format with month names directly from query.

You can also write your own formatting function in your programming language.

Comment: then what should we do, i do not want to format date using java code?